# Multitenancy with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, multi-tenant

I have an application in `ASP.NET MVC` amd `NHibernate`. I have to now implement **multitenancy** into it.
Here is how the scenario would look like -

1. When a user logs in, I will get the `CompanyCode` of the user.
2. I will run a query with the CompanyCode as parameter, I will get the username and password to his `SecuritySchema`.
3. I log in to the `SecuritySchema`.
4. I run another query that will give me the actual schema name where the database tables relevant to the user will be present.
5. I then log in to his schema and my application resumes.

What is the best way of implementing this? I have never done this before. How do I log in to another schema when my NHibernate session is already open with another schema?